# SwiftUI on Mac: Help Text Always Visible Even within View with Zero Opacity

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I have run into some unexpected behavior while using SwiftUI in a macOS app. I filed a Feedback with Apple in case it's a bug, but it might actually be designed to work this way, so I'm looking for a workaround.

I rely heavily on the use of `.opacity()` to show and hide different sections of my app with tabs. I don't use `if` clauses because each time the user changes the tab, you have to wait for the entire view to rebuild and that is pretty slow.

Here's a basic example that demonstrates the problem:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var viewAVisible = false
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      ZStack{
    
        Text("View A Visible")
          .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
          .background(Color.blue)
          .help("This is View A's help text. It should be invisible when View A is invisible.")
          .opacity(viewAVisible ? 1 : 0)
        
        Text("View B Visible")
          .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
          .background(Color.gray)
          .opacity(viewAVisible ? 0 : 1)
      }
    
      Button("Toggle"){
        viewAVisible.toggle()
      }
     
    }.padding()
  }
}
```

The default app state is to hide the "View A" `Text()` and only show the "View B" `Text()`. But if you hover over View B, you still see View A's `.help` text:

[image]

In my opinion, if a view has `.opacity(0)` then its help text shouldn't show up. But regardless, I need to find a way around this.

I thought about doing something like this:

```
.help(viewAVisible ? "This is View A's help text..." : "")
```

...but that doesn't scale across dozens of views in my app--particularly among child views that don't know if their parent view is shown or hidden. As I mouse across my app, I see the help text of tons of views all over the place even though they are invisible.

Has anyone run into this or have any suggestions on how to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug (they do not remove tracking rects), here is a demo of workaround - move help tag into background and remove it manually (tested with macOS 12.0.1)

```
Text("View A Visible")
    .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
    .background(Group {
        if viewAVisible {
            Color.blue.help("This is View A's help text. It should be invisible when View A is invisible.")
        } else {
            Color.clear
        }
    })
    .opacity(viewAVisible ? 1 : 0)
```